# Dynamically Add listbox Item to an ObservableCollection

Tags: listbox

I have a listbox that I have bound to an Observable collection. At runtime I would like the user to click a button and add thier own custom ID and Name to the listbox.
How do I do that when the listbox is already bound to an Observable collection?

THank you

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button add the item to the observable collection and the listbox should automatically update.  If not, call databind on the listbox after it's been added to the collection and this will rebind the data to the listbox updating it